How to find eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a matrix with variables
How can I find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a matrix with variables like this? My first thought was to assign a number, like 1, to one of them and solve it from there, but obviously, that's not going to work because the determinant has to be zero.
\begin{bmatrix}
2+b & 2b & \frac{1+2a+b}{a} \\
a & 3+2a & \frac{2+2a+b}{b} \\
-ab & -2ab & 1-2a-b
\end{bmatrix}

Denote the matrix by $M$. Have you tried finding roots of the characteristic polynomial $\det(xI - M)$?

Finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a matrix with variables is just like finding them with numbers. In this case, letting your matrix be denoted by $M$, we want to find the values $x$ such that $\det(M-Ix) = 0$ where $I$ is the $3\times 3$ identity matrix. We can compute this out and get that $\det(M-Ix) = -x^3+6x^2-11x+6$, and this equals $0$ when $x$ is $1$, $2$, and $3$.
Now we want to find the eigenvectors. I'll write out the case for $x=1$. We want to find $v$ such that $Mv=v$, which is the same as finding when $(M-I)v=0$.We can write this out as an augmented matrix
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
2+b-1 & 2b & \frac{1+2a+b}{b}  & 0 \\
a & 3+2a-1 & \frac{2+2a+b}{b} & 0 \\
-ab & -2ab & 1 - 2a - b - 1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
Row reducing this will give us
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1/a & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1/b & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
and so we have
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
v_1 + (1/a)v_3 = 0 \\
v_2 + (1/b)v_3 = 0
\end{cases}
\Rightarrow
v = 
\begin{pmatrix}
-1/a \\
-1/b \\
1
\end{pmatrix}v_3
\end{align*}
And so $(-1/a, -1/b, 1)^T$ is a basis for the eigenspace corresponding to the eigenvalue $x=1$.
